# How to merge 2 string columns in one dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

I have a dataset with 2 columns of gene names looking like this:

```
Gene_names1    Gene_names2
ACE                 .
BRCA                .
.                   SEP7
.                   CTFL
HER2                .
ZAP70               .
```

Is there a way for me to merge these columns in the same dataset to get an output:

```
Gene_names1    Gene_names2     Gene_names3
ACE                 .              ACE
BRCA                .              BRCA
.                   CTFL           CTFL
.                   CTFL           CTFL 
HER2                .              HER2              
ZAP70               .              ZAP70
```

I've been trying to answer this using similar questions, but most are with numeric data and I get errors wanting numeric values - is there a way to do this with strings?

For example I've tried:

```
df$Gene_names3 <- coalesce(df$Gene_names1, df$Gene_names2) #runs but is a replicate of Gene_names1

df$Gene_names3<-rowSums(df[, c("Gene_names1", "Gene_names2")], na.rm=T) #numeric error

df %>% mutate(Category = coalesce(Gene_names1, Gene_names2))
```

> Error: Column names `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `Z1` must not be duplicated.
>   Use .name_repair to specify repair.

I can see that something like `df[, Gene_names3 := Gene_names1][is.na(Gene_names1), Gene_names3 := Gene_names2][]` might work but I don't know how to change the `is.na()` to be "is ." if that makes sense.

I have 230 columns in total, Gene_names1 is actually column number 210 and Gene_names2 is column 222 for context.

```
structure(list(Gene_names1 = c("ACE", "BRCA", ".", ".", "HER2", 
"ZAP70"), Gene_names2 = c(".", ".", "SEP7", "CTFL", ".", "."
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Please give reproducible examples

Comment: Thank you, added that in now

Comment: `df$Gene_names3 <- gsub("[.]", "", paste0(df$Gene_names1, df$Gene_names2))`?

Comment: `coalesce` replaces missing (i.e. `NA`) values. You could replace those `.` representations of missing information with `NA`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `unlist`, filter out `.` and attach to your df, i.e.

```
 df$new <- unlist(df)[unlist(df) != '.']

#   Gene_names1 Gene_names2   new
#1:         ACE           .   ACE
#2:        BRCA           .  BRCA
#3:           .        SEP7  HER2
#4:           .        CTFL ZAP70
#5:        HER2           .  SEP7
#6:       ZAP70           .  CTFL
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have other columns with '.' will that confuse this? I have tried it with just ```df$new <- unlist(df$Gene_names1)[unlist(df$Gene_names2) != '.']``` which runs but the new column still have the `.`

Comment: Your output is a little strange. The order should be `ACE > BRCA > SEP7 > CTFL > HER2 > ZAP70`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fcoalesce`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x==".", NA))
df$Gene_names3 <- data.table::fcoalesce(df)
df

   Gene_names1 Gene_names2 Gene_names3
1:         ACE        <NA>         ACE
2:        BRCA        <NA>        BRCA
3:        <NA>        SEP7        SEP7
4:        <NA>        CTFL        CTFL
5:        HER2        <NA>        HER2
6:       ZAP70        <NA>       ZAP70
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply chose non-`"."` in each row using `apply`.

```
dat$Gene_names3 <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) x[!x == "."])
dat
#    Gene_names1 Gene_names2 Gene_names3
# 1:         ACE           .         ACE
# 2:        BRCA           .        BRCA
# 3:           .        SEP7        SEP7
# 4:           .        CTFL        CTFL
# 5:        HER2           .        HER2
# 6:       ZAP70           .       ZAP70
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have other columns with '.' will that confuse this?

Comment: @DN1 Not those with `"."`, if else is just one single cell with a value in each row. Be careful if there are spaces such as `". "`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unite` in `tidyr` to paste together multiple columns into one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(na_if, ".") %>% 
  unite("Gene_names3", sep = "", remove = F, na.rm = T)

  Gene_names3 Gene_names1 Gene_names2
1         ACE         ACE        <NA>
2        BRCA        BRCA        <NA>
3        SEP7        <NA>        SEP7
4        CTFL        <NA>        CTFL
5        HER2        HER2        <NA>
6       ZAP70       ZAP70        <NA>
```

Or

```
df %>%
  unite("Gene_names3", sep = "", remove = F) %>%
  mutate(Gene_names3 = sub("[.]", "", Gene_names3))
```